# Pygame window not responding error when i try to run a code

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random

black  = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Speeding cars")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def drive(self, change):
        self.change = random.randint(1, 2)
        self.x += self.change
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))

    def again(self):
        while True:
            if self.x + 50 > 1200:
                for car in cars:
                    car.drive(False)

cars = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    cars.append(Car(0, i*100, 50, 25))

driving = True

while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    for car in cars:
        car.drive(False)
        car.again()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Whenever i try to run this code, my pygame window stops responding.  Something i have noticed is whenever i delete `def again(self):` block of code, my winodw works fine, however i want the blocks to come back again after they go off the screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've implemented an endless loop in `again`:

> ```py
> def again(self):
>    while True:
>        if self.x + 50 > 1200:
>            for car in cars:
>                car.drive(False)
> ```

Note, `again` is called in the main application loop and it is called for each car:

> ```py
> while driving:
>    # [...]
>
>    for car in cars:
>        # [...]
>        car.again()
> ```

---

If you want to set all the cars at its initial position, when 1 car has reached the end of the track, then you've to verify if any car has reached the end of the track and to est the `.x` coordinate of all cars 0:

```py
finished = [car for car in cars if car.x + 50 > 1200]
if len(finished) > 0:
    for car in cars:
        car.x = 0
```

or a bit shorter

```py
if any([car for car in cars if car.x + 50 > 1200]):
    for car in cars:
        car.x = 0
```

Do the evaluation in the main application loop:

```py
driving = True
while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    for car in cars:
        car.drive(False)

    if any([car for car in cars if car.x + 50 > 1200]):
        for car in cars:
            car.x = 0 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

If you want to keep the individual position of each car, then just set a single car at the start, when it reaches the end of the track (`car.x -= 1200`):

```py
class Car:
    # [...]

    def again(self):
        if self.x + 50 > 1200:
            self.x -= 1200
```

```py
driving = True
while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    for car in cars:
        car.drive(False)
        car.again()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I did that the first time i was writing this code . It dosent give me any errors but dosent give me the desired result either.

Comment: Also i noticed you used 'self.drive(False)' self instead of 'car.drive(False)' Is there any difference or any advantage of using self over car ?

Comment: @hippozhipos 1. Your question is *"Pygame window not responding error [...]"*. It that gives not the desired result then you've to explain what you want to do. 2. In my code there is no `car` in the method. The name of the object instance is `self` and `self` is the `car` from the call `self.drive(False)`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want the blocks to come back over and over again everytime it goes off the screen.